# C++ Why was the copy constructor called?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    A(const A& a) { cout << "A::A(A&)" << endl; }
};

class B {
public:
    explicit B(A aa) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it print "A::A(A&)"?

When was the copy constructor for "A" called? And if the code calls the copy constructor, why can I remove the copy constructor without creating a compilation error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`B(A aa)` takes an `A` by value, so when you execute `B b(a)` the compiler calls the copy constructor `A(const A& a)` to generate the instance of `A` named `aa` in the `explicit` constructor for `B`.

The reason you can remove the copy constructor and have this still work is that the compiler will generate a copy constructor for you in cases where you have not also declared a move constructor.

*Note: The compiler generated copy constructor is often not sufficient for complex classes, it performs a simple member wise copy, so for complex elements or dynamically allocated memory you should declare your own.*

> § 15.8.1
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, a non-explicit one is declared implicitly.
>   If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy
>   constructor is defined as deleted; otherwise, it is defined as defaulted (11.4). The latter case is deprecated if
>   the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator or a user-declared destructor or assignment operator.

Comment: The compiler generated copy constructor should have no problem with "complex elements", if said elements are of a type that has been written correctly.

Answer (score 7):

**Why the copy happens**

Look at your `class B` c'tor:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(A aa) {}
};
```

You receive A by **value**, triggering a copy during the call.

If you would have change it to (notice `A & aa`):

```
class B {
public:
    explicit B(A & aa) {}
};
```

There wouldn't be any copy...

**Default copy constructor**

When you remove the c'tor, the compiler generates one for you when it can trivially do so:

> First, you should understand that if you do not declare a copy
>   constructor, the compiler gives you one implicitly. The implicit
>   copy constructor does a member-wise copy of the source object.

The default c'tor is equivalent to:

```
MyClass::MyClass( const MyClass& other ) :
     x( other.x ), c( other.c ), s( other.s ) {}
```